# rake db:migrate fails due to duplicate table - wants to start migration from beginning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake, rails-migrations

So, everything was going swimmingly until I install the surveyor gem, and then uninstalled.

Ive since tried to add 3 tables: questions, surveys, and responses via the rails g scaffold command. On trying to run rake db:migrate, it fails on the first migrate (create outcomes table) and fires a PG duplicate table error. Ive tried rake db:rollback and then running the migrate again but to no avail!

Is it normal for the migrations to start at the very first migration? And secondly, how can I fix it so that it runs the remaining migrations?

Many thanks,

Mike

Comment: Ive since tried rake db:schema:load and this has properly ruined it. On examination with PGAdmin, most of my tables now no longer contain any columns whatsoever!

Comment: Presumably the gem created those tables and you didn't uninstall it properly, right? You could always delete the tables manually through `psql`.

Comment: The gem did create the questions, surveys, and responses tables, however it did not create the outcomes table. That is a separate table from a previous version of the app. I have manually deleted the offending tables but the migration is still crashing!

Comment: Or as a shortcut, you can add in your first migration file `change` or `up` method, `remove_table :outcomes`. Once the migration run, you can remove that line `remove_table :outcomes`.

Comment: It just fails on the next migration down then instead. Is it normal behaviour for the migrations to keep starting from the beginning again?

Comment: It sounds like you're properly foobared yourself. It is normal behavior for migrations to start from the last finished migration as recorded in schema_migrations. With postgres, migrations are transactional, meaning if they fail partway, they roll back the changes made in that migration.

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that I have accidentally deleted the schema_migrations table. Is there any way to change the version number. I have tried using PGAdmin but it says that I cannot edit data in a table without primary key or OIDS.

Comment: So... Im probably using a hammer to break a nut, but I deleted every table and ran the migrations again. Everything seems to be working correctly now. Thanks for your help guys. Merry Christmas.